# How can I delete a contact that has cases opened by him?

Tags: customer-portal, case

I need to delete a contact, that has closed and open cases created by him. that were created by the self service portal.

Trying to delete it, I get the standard window that shows the cases attached, and a message it can not be deleted.

Is there a way I can transfer/change the creator?

Answer (score 3):

You can not delete the either `Account` or `Contact` if Case record is related to it regardless of Closed or Open, You should first need to delete the `Case` associated with the `Contact` and then you can delete the contact.
This can also be done by changing the `Contact` field of `Case` by some other `Contact` and then delete the contact after updating the `Case` associated with it.